# batch file to copy files older than 30 minutes from one folder to another

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

How can I copy files which are older than 30 minutes from current time from one folder to another one?

Comment: Do you _really_ want DOS or do you want the Windows command shell?

Answer (score 3):

There are several Windows ports for the *nix `find` command available, offering switches like `-mmin` and `-mtime` that would be useful here, allowing the problem to be solved with a one-liner…
Note that Powershell certainly is a viable alternative to [achieve this goal](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176988.aspx#EBAA).

In plain DOS, here is a rather limited batch script, but it suffices as a base to solve your problem:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

call :GetRefTimestamp -30
for %%f in (*) do (
    call :GetFileTimestamp "%%~tf"
    if "!filetimestamp!" LSS "!reftimestamp!" echo -- %%f is older than 30 minutes
    if NOT "!filetimestamp!" LSS "!reftimestamp!" echo ++ %%f is NOT older than 30 minutes
)

endlocal
goto :EOF

:GetRefTimestamp
::get current date/time
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-5 delims=/:, " %%f in (`echo %DATE:~-10% %TIME: =0%`) do set reftimestamp=%%h%%g%%fT%%i%%j
::apply delta (format [-]HHMM) on time part - not handling over/underflow
set /a timedelta=%~1
set timedeltasign=
if %timedelta% LSS 0 set timedeltasign=-
set timeHHMM=%timestamp:~-4%
set /a timeHHMM+=timedelta
set /a timeMM=timeHHMM %% 100
if %timeMM% GEQ 60 set /a timeHHMM+=%timedeltasign%40
set timeHHMM=000%timeHHMM%
set reftimestamp=%reftimestamp:~0,-4%%timeHHMM:~-4%
goto :EOF

:GetFileTimestamp
::get file date/time
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-5 delims=/:, " %%f in (`echo %~1`) do set filetimestamp=%%h%%g%%fT%%i%%j
goto :EOF
```

Just use common sense for the delta (knowing the limitations) and refrain from using leading zeroes :]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use robocopy (or forfiles)

robocopy is part of win2003 rtk and is installed on vista and windows 7 by default -> 
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en

FORFILES is part of Windows 2000/NT resource kit but works fine on XP/Vista/7 ->
(I think it is not available on microsoft site anymore)

h_ttp://www.petri.co.il/download_free_reskit_tools.htm